# keyboard keys does not work in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.o4. All the keys work but **Space** and **B** do not work. When I attach an external keyboard, both the keys work from there. I am Windows 11 installed in another drive and when I boot from Windows, both the keys work there. What might be the issue?

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and choose your laptop (I assume) keyboard model.

Comment: @Esther it is currently selected Generic 105 Key PC. The buttons stop working sometimes and I need to restart a number of times to get it back

Comment: my laptop model is "HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec2xxx"

Comment: Are you using a language other than English for your keyboard layout?

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 i am using two different languages but default is english and it does not work on it. I did not try for the other language. The other language is Urdu(Pakistan)

Comment: Hmm. Can you try booting from a live USB and see if the keys work there? I'm thinking maybe the locale settings are causing trouble.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 the keys sometime work but sometimes does not. these are currently working after a number of reboots to the system